# How to differentiate between namespaces of injected modules in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, angularjs

Lets say I have a controller, which depends on two modules that both contain a directive or a service with the same name. Can I specify which one exactly should be used?

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['secondModule', 'thirdModule'])
    .controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'myService', function(scope, myService){
        scope.user = myService.getUser();   
        console.log(myService); 
}]);
```

In this case both **secondModule** and **thirdModule** have a service called **myService**. But only the one from the **thirdModule** will be used in this example. I tried putting something like **secondModule.myService** as a dependency for **Ctrl1**, but it wouldn't work. Is there some kind of namespacing in AngularJS?

Comment: you should really avoid this!! at the moment this does not seem possible

Comment: This seems like a real issue when developing large scale apps which could have many directives/services/constants etc. Using simple naming conventions isn't a strong enough mechanism imo.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, no, there is no module based namespacing. You'll have to avoid collisions on your own.

I believe there was some discussion about this, but I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following convention: https://github.com/roytruelove/angular-grunt-coffeescript#modules-and-angular-items

Answer (score 0):

How about namespacing the services (and also controllers)?

```
angular.module('secondModule', [])
    .factory('secondModule.myService', function($http) {
        return {
            getUser: function() { /* some code here */ }
        };
    });

angular.module('thirdModule', [])
    .factory('thirdModule.myService', function($http) {
        return {
            getGroup: function() { /* some code here */ }
        };
    });

angular.module('myApp', ['secondModule', 'thirdModule'])
    .controller('myApp.Ctrl1',
        ['$scope', 'secondModule.myService', function(scope, myService){
            scope.user = myService.getUser();   
            console.log(myService); 
        }]
    );
```